# VB.net Count specific text items in a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, count, listbox

been going around in circles for the past week with this code despite knowing its very simple, I'm having a lot of issues.

I'm creating a simple restaurant menu for a college assignment, where a user selects what items they want then it calculates the final price and displays that in a label.

I have set it out very simple, with each food item in a label on the form and a button next to it displaying 'Add'. When clicked it then adds it to the listbox. The user has the option of adding multiples of each item and also deleting the items, all of which I have sorted out without a hitch.

What I want to happen is when I click the 'Calculate' button, I want to search the listbox for each item, count how many there of that and add the relevant value for each one. For example, if I add 3 Garlic Bread to the listbox, I want the calculate button to search the listbox for garlic bread and for each time it appears add 1.20. I need this for each item.

If anyone could help would really help :D

If it helps, I'm working in one form called 'Form1', my list box is called 'Listbox1', I have 20 food items as well.

I did ask this question the other day and while the information was useful when I asked for an explanation as to how I would translate it into my project, it made no sense at all. I know this may be difficult but please understand I'm new to VB so if you could explain everything like I'm 5 it would be greatly appreciated :D

Cheers

Comment: You need to add, to your question, the code used to fill the ListBox

Comment: When the button 'Add' is clicked the Code is     ListBox1.Items.Add(Label1.Text)   .Just this repeated for each object as it seems to be the easiest to layout and keep organised. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to create a Dictionary for this with the item names as key and the price as value. Make this dictionary a global variable and populate it in the Form.Load event:

```
Dim MenuItems As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MenuItems = New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
    MenuItems.Add("Garlic Bread", 12.23)
    MenuItems.Add("Roast Beef", 2.23)
    (...)
End Sub
```

In your calculate method you would iterate through your list and lookup in the dictionary for the price:

```
Dim TotalPrice As Decimal = 0
For Each item As Object In Listbox1.Items
    If MenuItems.ContainsKey(item.ToString) Then TotalPrice += MenuItems(item.ToString)
Next
Return TotalPrice
```

If you do it like that you could even create your menu dynamically from the dictionary (add labels and buttons for every item in the dictionary to the form at form load).

Comment: Hi Jens, Perfect code, Thank you so so much, if I could kiss you I would :D

Comment: Hi Jens, one slight error for the 'For Each item As Object In Listbox1' line, I'm getting a Expression type error, any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot the `.Items`. See my edited post.

Comment: Cheers, one last question sorry to bother you, I've replaced the 'return totalprice' line ,as it didnt work, with label48.text = totalprice however no matter what items are in the listbox it keeps returning 0, any ideas?

Comment: Hi sorry my fault, had an additional value in my list thanks for all your help it works perfectly :D